# WCF nettcpbinding "send" timeout -- after all data was transmitted

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-3.5, timeout, nettcpbinding

I'm writing a local-machine client/server application using an application-hosted WCF service over nettcpbinding with a duplex channel (i.e., peer-to-peer communication). For legacy reasons, this is .NET 3.5.

This code sets up the server:

```
var netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);
netTcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
netTcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;

netTcpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 14);
netTcpBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
netTcpBinding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
netTcpBinding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);

netTcpBinding.ListenBacklog = 2;
netTcpBinding.MaxConnections = 200;
netTcpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
netTcpBinding.MaxBufferSize = 10* 1000 * 1000;
netTcpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10* 1000 * 1000;
netTcpBinding.PortSharingEnabled = true;

netTcpBinding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
netTcpBinding.ReliableSession.Ordered = true;
netTcpBinding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59);

ISmartBrowserClientServiceCallback callback = new SmartBrowserClientServiceCallback();
InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(callback);

smartBrowserServiceFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<ClientService.ISmartBrowserClientService>(
    context,
    netTcpBinding,
    new EndpointAddress(uri));

this.channel = this.smartBrowserServiceFactory.CreateChannel();
```

This code sets up the client:

```
var netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);
netTcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
netTcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;

netTcpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59);
netTcpBinding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15); // timeout seconds are different to help debugging
netTcpBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 17);
netTcpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 19);
netTcpBinding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 21);

netTcpBinding.ListenBacklog = 2;
netTcpBinding.MaxConnections = 100;
netTcpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
netTcpBinding.MaxBufferSize = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
netTcpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
netTcpBinding.PortSharingEnabled = true;

netTcpBinding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
netTcpBinding.ReliableSession.Ordered = true;
netTcpBinding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59);

ISmartBrowserClientServiceCallback callback = new SmartBrowserClientServiceCallback(this.smartBrowserClient);
InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(callback);

this.smartBrowserServiceFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<ISmartBrowserClientService>(
    context,
    netTcpBinding,
    new EndpointAddress(new Uri(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "net.tcp://localhost:{0}/Cpy.SmartBrowser.SmartBrowserClientService/", defaultPort.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))));

this.smartBrowserServiceFactory.Faulted += (sender, e) =>
{
    this.smartBrowserServiceFactory = null;
};

this.channel = this.smartBrowserServiceFactory.CreateChannel();
```

Now, when a client calls a service method with some data, that data is well received by the service, which acts upon it, but for some reason there's a `TimeoutException` on the sender after 17 seconds, the value I picked for the `SendTimeout`. I find this strange, because all data to send was already sent, instantly, and I see no reason for the system to wait for anything.

This client/server app will be used on a local machine with a single service and a single client, just peer-to-peer communicating. But if I can't get rid of this timeout, I'll have to work around it in a dirty way, which I want to avoid.

What obvious thing am I missing?

Comment: What does the server code do when it finishes servicing the request? Does it return? How long does it take for the server to complete the action?

Comment: The code returns a response, and this is well within a second.